# увеличение памяти при циклах скрипта

Tags: python-3.x

при запуске скрипта увеличивается память(частный рабочий набор) и свободная уменьшается в диспетчере задач!как сбрасывать и почему не освобождает?скрипт такой

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time
from importlib import reload
import example
n = int()
def start():
    n = 2+2
    print(n,type(n))
    #time.sleep(1)
    startv()

def startv():
    x = n + 1
    print(x,type(x))
    reload(example)
while True:
    print("тут")
    start()
```

Comment: Возникает вопрос, что вы делаете в модуле `example`, что его нужно принудительно перезагружать?

Comment: пытаюсь от рекурсии уйти(а то до 1000 и ошибка)!сам код находится в файле с этим именем.

Comment: Переделывая рекурсию функций в рекурсию модулей вы не избавитесь от нее. Вам нужно всего лишь сделать обычный цикл (`while` или `for`) вместо рекурсии.

Comment: без них никак!?!

Comment: Что значит "без них никак"? Именно через них циклы и делаются. Рекурсия нужна только в очень специфических случаях (обход дерева, например).

Comment: а пямять почему растет?

Comment: А кто его знает. Скорее всего из-за того что это все равно рекурсия, просто реализованная через какой-то выверт. Вообще reload не для этого, его очень редко на практике используют.